# Elixir: try .. rescue around decorator

Tags: macros, elixir, try-catch, decorator

I am looking into [Nebulex.Caching](https://github.com/cabol/nebulex/blob/v2.0.0-rc.2/lib/nebulex/caching.ex#L300) and use the followint decorator:

```
@decorate cacheable(cache: Cache, key: name)
def get_by_name(name, age) do
   # your logic (maybe the loader to retrieve the value from the SoR)
end
```

It works perfectly. However, when I turn off Redis, it fails with `Elixir.Redix.ConnectionError`. This issue is well described here: https://github.com/cabol/nebulex_ecto/issues/6

I tried to write my own decorator and reuse the code from `Nebulex.Caching`:

```
defmodule Coups.Inventory.Cache.Decorator do

  use Decorator.Define, [safe_cacheable: 1]
  require Logger

  def safe_cacheable(attrs, block, context) do
      try do
          Nebulex.Caching.cacheable(attrs, block, context)
      rescue Elixir.Redix.ConnectionError ->
        quote do
          unquote(block)
        end
      end
  end
end
```

However, it didn't change anything, and the exception was not caught. How can I achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Seems like your decorator executes at compile time, but the exception is at runtime. I'm not sure what the solution would be. Maybe you can move the try/rescue into the quote block?